# Добавление в конец вектора пар

Tags: c++

Имею вектор:

```
vector <pair<int, int> > factor;
```

Добавление через индекс понятно как делать:

```
factor[i].first = q;
```

А как сделать через `push_back?`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Например,

```
factor.push_back(make_pair(1,2));
factor.push_back({3,4});
```

или даже так -

```
factor.emplace_back(5,6);
```

Answer (score 1):

В дополнение к ответу Harry - еще можно

```
factor.push_back(pair<int,int>(3,4));
```